# Issue - Regex capturing superset

Tags: regex

I'm trying to fetch the `Value` and `ValueRef` pairs out of the text like below.

Issue-My regex is capturing the text from preceding Value, but I want it to be tightly bounded. Should I need to ignore using negative look head?

The Regex and sample text is here -
https://regex101.com/r/dT4wD3/1

`:{"Value":"Chairman of the Presidium of the Revolutionary Council","ValueType":1}}],"ValueReferences":[{"Value":"Chairman","ValueRef":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_of_Afghanistan"}`

What I need are 2 pairs -

1. `"Value":"Chairman","ValueRef":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/President_of_Afghanistan"`
2. `"Value":"Revolutionary ouncil","ValueRef":"http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revolutionary_Council_(Afghanistan)"`

Comment: As many others here will also tell you, regex might not be the the right tool for parsing JSON.

Comment: The string looks like JSON, why don't use parse it to JSON and get value from it using normal object methods.

Answer (score 1):

Use `.*"Value":"([^"]*)","ValueRef":"([^"]*)".*` and `$1` and `$2` will give you the *Value* and *ValueRef* respectively. But it's not a very safe way to do it in case of JSON character escapes and maybe other structural stuff.

As the others already suggested - try to use the ***[Gson](https://github.com/google/gson)*** library for Java (or what fits your programming environment) instead to parse stuff like this nicely and robustly if possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
{"Value":"([^"]*)","ValueRef":"([^"]*)"}
```

Use negation based regex.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/dT4wD3/2